# CloudKit was Working but Getting a Permission Error All of a Sudden

Tags: swift, xcode, cloudkit

I had CloudKit working for the last couple weeks and this morning when I was trying to save a record, something I had done a number of times before, I started getting a Permission Error

```
Error saving to CloudKit: <CKError 0x600001f48ed0: "Permission Failure" 
(10/2007); server message = "Operation not permitted"; uuid = 78FA3DD1- 
EA44-4701-9A7E-8291F076DD8F; container ID = "[CloudKit Container Name]"> - Error fetching auth tokens from server: 
Operation not permitted'
```

So I have triple checked that it's requesting to the right container, which it is (I only have two containers setup on my CloudKit so it's an easy check.

I have turned off and turned CloudKit on again in XCode as an attempt to force reset it (not sure if that did anything helpful but figured I would give it a shot)

In case this is needed, this is how I am saving to CloudKit (had no problem with this bit of code in the past.

```
func createRecord(title: String, type: String, comment: String) {
    let audioRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Audio")

    audioRecord["title"] = title as CKRecordValue
    audioRecord["type"] = type as CKRecordValue
    audioRecord["comment"] = comment as CKRecordValue


    let audioURL = audioRecorder.getAudioURL()
    let audioAsset = CKAsset(fileURL: audioURL)
    audioRecord["audio"] = audioAsset

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.save(audioRecord) { [self] record, error in
            //print(CKContainer.default())
            if let error = error {
                print("Error saving to CloudKit: \(error.self) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Record has been successfully saved to CloudKit")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know the user is logged into their iCloud account?

Comment: How do you know the device has WiFi connection?

Comment: @ElTomato
I have checked both scenarios by running the app on both the simulator and my personal device (checking both the connection and that the user is signed in), but thank you for the response sometimes it can be these small things

Comment: Have you found out what auth tokens are?

Comment: I understand that to be CloudKit's way of authentication, kind of like saying "Yes, the user making the request is an active iCloud account". This was why my first check was running it on my device where I am logged in (I was logged in on the simulator as well, but figured I would know this to be working as a fact on my own device), but still getting the permission error. Will do some more troubleshooting.

Other's have said it can be an intermittent issue so we'll see what happens when I get back to it this evening.